# Adding NPM module in React Native Throws Error (unable to resolve module url)

Tags: npm, react-native

To be specific I'm using `meta-extractor` module in react native.

```
'use strict';
//import React Native
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight, 
} from 'react-native';


var styles = require('../styles/styles');
var metagetplus = require('../../node_modules/meta-extractor');
```

Here is the error message:

*Unable to resolve module url from /Users/name/Desktop/instaldr/node_modules/meta-extractor/index.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/url and its parent directories
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968*

*To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.*

I tried all suggested resolution methods mentioned in that link, but nothing seems to solve the issue. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: If the `meta-extractor` module is in your node_modules, couldn't you just `require('meta-extractor')`?

Comment: Initially I had kept it like that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Importing components changed, should not use require anymore, try:
    import metagetplus from ('meta-extractor')

Comment: `import metagetplus from ('meta-extractor');` throws 'unexpected token' error.

Comment: `import metagetplus from 'meta-extractor';` gives the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Have you seen the package.json ... if the package "meta-extractor" is not listed in package.json it might break the whole system ?
2 . Try to use the commonjs require method :

```
const metagetplus = require('meta-extractor');
```

Sometimes modules only work with commonjs require method ... it might not work with import statements all the time . the package "meta-extractor" hasn't been updated for quite a while so it might not jut work with import statements ...

So what you can do is this ...

1 . Clear watchman : `watchman watch-del-all`
2 . Clear node_modules : `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
3 . Install the package : `npm i meta-extractor`
4 . Edit code file :

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight, 
} from 'react-native';


const styles = require('../styles/styles');
const metagetplus = require('meta-extractor');
```

Hope it works ...